# Summing an array of numbers in ruby and extracting time over 40 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I wrote a payroll type app which takes a `clock_event` and has a `punch_in` and `punch_out` field.  In a the `clock_event` class I have a method that takes the employee, sums their total hours and exports to CSV.  This gives total hours for the employee, and then a total sum of their total_hours which is a method in the class calculated on the fly.

Here is my code:

**clock_event.rb**

```
 def total_hours
    self.clock_out.to_i - self.clock_in.to_i
  end

  def self.to_csv(records = [], options = {})
          CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << ["Employee", "Clock-In", "Clock-Out", "Station", "Comment", "Total Shift Hours"]
              records.each do |ce|
              csv << [ce.user.try(:full_name), ce.formatted_clock_in, ce.formatted_clock_out, ce.station.try(:station_name), ce.comment, TimeFormatter.format_time(ce.total_hours)]
            end
           records.map(&:user).uniq.each do |user|
             csv << ["Total Hours for: #{user.full_name}"]
             csv << [TimeFormatter.format_time(records.select{ |r| r.user == user}.sum(&:total_hours))]
           end

            csv << ["Total Payroll Hours"]
            csv << [TimeFormatter.format_time(records.sum(&:total_hours))]
          end
        end
    end
```

This method works and exports a CSV with all total time entries for each day then a sum of the hours at the bottom of the CSV file.

Here's my problem...

I can sum no problem, but I need to show the following:

1. Total Sum of hours (done)
2. Any hours over 40 hours I need to pull that amount into another field in the CSV file.  So if an employee hits 40 hours it will show the 40 hours in one field then show the remaining ours as overtime right next to it.

I know how to sum the hours but am unsure as to how to extra the hours over 40 into another field into the CSV.

I'm sure there's a Ruby way to do it but I'm not certain on how this would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you need more code or context, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should let total_hours return exactly what it says it returns in its method definition, the "total hours".  Include your time formatting within this method to avoid scattering TimeFormatter logic through out your codebase:

```
def total_hours
  TimeFormatter.format_time(self.clock_out.to_i - self.clock_in.to_i)
end
```

Second, you need to calculate overtime hours situationally, that will look like this:

```
def overtime_hours(num_weeks = 1, hours_per_week = 40)
  ot = total_hours - (num_weeks * hours_per_week)
  ot > 0 ? ot : 0
end
```

This gives you some customization so that if your business rules ever change you can actually maintain your code a little easier.  Your defaults will always be 1 week and 40 hours, however you may do this:

```
ce.overtime_hours(2, 40)
```

or:

```
ce.overtime_hours(2, 39)
```

Some people only work 39 hours so that businesses can avoid paying for healthcare and other mandatory benefits that kick in at 40 hours.  This will give you the ability to control what overtime_hours outputs.

And in your CSV for Week 1:

```
records.where('user_id is ? and date > ? and date < ?', user.id, begin_week_1, end_week_1).sum(&:overtime_hours)
```

and week 2:

```
records.where('user_id is ? and date > ? and date < ?', user.id, begin_week_2, end_week_2).sum(&:overtime_hours)
```

Comment: I dont think -40 will work since time is calculated in seconds.  So I did this          csv << ["Overtime Hours for: #{user.full_name}"]
         csv << [TimeFormatter.format_time(records.select{ |r| r.user == user}.sum(&:total_hours) - 144000)] which takes the total hours and subtracts 40 hours in seconds from the sum of total_hours.  This gives me the right number.

Comment: Be careful, you will get negative time in there if you're under 40 hours.

Comment: This will work if I'm running timecards for a 1 week range but I'm trying to figure out how to do this sort of calculation on a two week period because payroll is calculated as 40 hours a week and overtime must be separated by week. Any thoughts on how to split out between two weeks?

Comment: @shakycode unless you have a way to get the clock_in and clock_out for individual weeks, this is probably impossible.  You really need to know the time for a single week, and then you need to calculate OT for that week in your CSV.  Then you need the second week, and you need to calculate OT for that second week.